# Usage of 'As an example'

Tags: word-usage

How about this sentence?

> As an example, let us consider the cases a=3 and a=5.

Should it be

> As examples?

Answer (score 3):

Both are possible, it depends on what you are trying to say

> As examples

is correct, if a=3 and a=5 produces two different outcomes, each will be **an example**.

> For example

can be used as a general introduction to what the examples will be.

> **For example**, he not only runs but he can also skate.
>   **As examples** of his athletic prowess, be can also run and skate.